# Can anyone make this task clearer, I don't really get it. It's my homework but I kinda stuck on what to do

Tags: search, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online

Demonstrate a Custom Site Page which shows all records on a Site’s Pages Library whose Custom Field (i.e. Region) matches the user-provided filter-value (i.e. North America, Southeast Asia)

Here's the task and I really don't get it.

Answer (score 1):

Depending upon the type of sharepoint api (Object model/csom/jsom) you are using you would form an appropriate caml query and pass it to sharepoint to get the results.

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention a SharePoint version, so I'll assume it is not SharePoint Online using the Modern UI.

I won't do your homework for you... but here's a hint: Web part page and Filter web parts.